# CFfile -- value is not set to the queried data

Tags: coldfusion, file, uploading, cfc, cffile

I have this add user form, it also doubles as a edit user form by querying the data and setting the value="#query.xvalue#". If the user exists (eg, you're editing a user, it loads in the users data from the database. When doing this on the `<cffile` field it does not load in the data, then when the insert goes to insert data it overrights the database values with a blank string (If a user does not input a new file). How do I avoid this?

Code:

Form:

```
<br/>Digital Copy<br/>
<!--- If null, set a default if not, set the default to database default --->
<cfif len(Trim(certificationsList.cprAdultImage)) EQ 0>
 <cfinput type="file" required="no" name="cprAdultImage" value="" >
 <cfelse>
    File Exists: <cfoutput><a href="#certificationsList.cprAdultImage#">View File</a></cfoutput>
    <cfinput type="file" required="no" name="cprAdultImage"  value="#certificationsList.cprAdultImage#">
</cfif>
```

Form Processor:

```
<!--- Has a file been specificed? ---> 
<cfif not len(Trim(form.cprAdultImage)) EQ 0>
    <cffile action="upload" filefield="cprAdultImage" destination="#destination#" nameConflict="makeUnique">
    <cfinvokeargument name="cprAdultImage" value="#pathOfFile##cffile.serverFile#">
<cfelse>
    <cfinvokeargument name="cprAdultImage" value="">
</cfif>
```

CFC

ARGS:

```
<cfargument name="cprAdultExp" required="NO">
<cfargument name="cprAdultCompany" type="string" required="no">
<cfargument name="cprAdultImage" type="string" required="no">
<cfargument name="cprAdultOnFile" type="boolean" required="no">
```

Query:

```
UPDATE mod_StudentCertifications
SET 
cprAdultExp='#DateFormat(ARGUMENTS.cprAdultExp, "mm/dd/yyyy")#',
cprAdultCompany='#Trim(ARGUMENTS.cprAdultCompany)#',
cprAdultImage='#Trim(ARGUMENTS.cprAdultImage)#',
cprAdultOnFile='#Trim(ARGUMENTS.cprAdultOnFile)#'

INSERT INTO 
mod_StudentCertifications(
cprAdultExp,
cprAdultcompany,
cprAdultImage,
cprAdultOnFile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <cfif not
>   len(Trim(form.cprAdultImage)) EQ 0>

That is actually doing the reverse of what you want. I believe what you are trying to say is:

```
<!--- if the length is greater than 0, assume a file was uploaded --->
<cfif len(Trim(form.cprAdultImage)) GT 0>
     file is not empty. do the upload ...
     <cfinvokeargument name="cprAdultImage" value="#pathOfFile##cffile.serverFile#">
<cfelse>
    <cfinvokeargument name="cprAdultImage" value="">
</cfif>
```

**Edit**
As an aside, .. since all of your arguments are optional, the code feels a bit awkward.

> <cfinput type="file" required="no" name="cprAdultImage"  value="#certificationsList.cprAdultImage#">,

You cannot really preset the file control "value" (browser security restrictions). Since a user can upload a file in both cases, just provide an input and display the "view" link only if a previous image exists.

```
<cfif len(Trim(certificationsList.cprAdultImage))>
    File Exists: 
    <cfoutput><a href="#certificationsList.cprAdultImage#">View File</a></cfoutput>
</cfif>        
<cfinput type="file" required="no" name="cprAdultImage">
```

> cprAdultImage='#Trim(ARGUMENTS.cprAdultImage)#',

The UPDATE logic looks a bit off as well. If a file was not supplied, you will end up overwriting the existing image with an empty string. To avoid that, only update that field *if* a new file was supplied (ie non-empty)

Form processing:

```
<cfif len(Trim(form.cprAdultImage)) GT 0>
    <cffile action="upload" filefield="cprAdultImage" destination="#destination#" nameConflict="makeUnique">
    <cfinvokeargument name="cprAdultImage" value="#pathOfFile##cffile.serverFile#">
</cfif>
```

CFC ARGS:

```
<!--- if values are always used in queries, should be required=true --->
<cfargument name="cprAdultExp" required="yes">
<cfargument name="cprAdultCompany" type="string" required="yes">
<cfargument name="cprAdultOnFile" type="boolean" required="yes">   
<cfargument name="cprAdultImage" type="string" default="">
```

Query

```
UPDATE mod_StudentCertifications
SET 
cprAdultExp='#DateFormat(ARGUMENTS.cprAdultExp, "mm/dd/yyyy")#',
cprAdultCompany='#Trim(ARGUMENTS.cprAdultCompany)#',
<!--- only overwrite the value if a new file was supplied --->
<cfif len(trim(ARGUMENTS.cprAdultImage))>
   cprAdultImage='#Trim(ARGUMENTS.cprAdultImage)#',
</cfif>
cprAdultOnFile='#Trim(ARGUMENTS.cprAdultOnFile)#'
WHERE ....
```

And do not forget cleanup. Remove any old files...

Comment: I was afraid of that. what should I put in the else?

Comment: The code would be exactly the same, just fix the CFIF. I have updated my response to make it more clear. Though passing an empty string seems a bit odd .. given that your cfargument is optional.